# What happens with injects after session bean passivation?

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi

Let's say we have a `@SessionScoped` bean which has one property which is being injected with `@Inject`. This inject is succesful when the bean is constructed. Now since the session isn't used for some time, the bean gets serialized to disk and is removed from memory. After some time the session gets used again, the bean is deserialized from disk and reinstantiated. The type of the property was a non serializable class.

**What happens with the injected properties?**
Do they stay null?
Do they get injected again?

I can't find any specific information about this use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What actually gets injected is not the property itself, but a dynamic proxy to it. This means that when your `@SessionScoped` bean gets deserialized and used again, the property is resolved again. See [this post](https://community.jboss.org/blogs/stuartdouglas/2010/10/12/weld-cdi-and-proxies) for more details. It is Weld specific, but gives you a good idea of what happens. It is however mandated by the spec (see section 5.4 of [spec](https://community.jboss.org/blogs/stuartdouglas/2010/10/12/weld-cdi-and-proxies)), so the other implementations will do it as well.